# TableView y su dataSource

Tags: swift, swift2

Recién intentando hacer una simple app, no pude hacer algo lo cual no entiendo porque no pude...

Teniendo la siguiente interfaz de usuario:

[image: UI]

y los siguientes archivos:

[image: .Swift - Controladores]

Bueno, lo que intente hacer es que cada tableView en mi `viewController` principal, tenga su propio `tableViewController` al cual le pasaría el delegado y dataSource pero no me dejó ni siquiera enlazar el `tableView` con su `tableViewController`

Comment: Estoy pensando que sea porque tableView no es un controller, y por eso no lo puedo enlazar con el tableViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactamente, como dices en el comentario esas dos tablas no son Controllers, por tanto no puedes asociarle una clase controller a cada una. Si quieres manipular y poblar esas tablas puedes hacerlo desde el propio ViewController principal, te pongo un ejemplo:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    // MARK: Propiedades

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView1: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView2: UITableView!

    // Datos para popular las tablas
    let muestraDatos1 = ["Uno", "Dos", "Tres", "Cuatro"]
    let muestraDatos2 = ["Uno", "Dos", "Tres", "Cuatro", "Cinco", "Seis", "Siete"]


    // MARK: Metodos

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Puedes hacer la asociacion aqui o en el storyboard
        tableView1.dataSource = self
        tableView1.delegate = self
        tableView1.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell1")

        // Puedes hacer la asociacion aqui o en el storyboard
        tableView2.dataSource = self
        tableView2.delegate = self
        tableView2.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell2")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if tableView == self.tableView1 {
            return muestraDatos1.count
        } else {
            return muestraDatos2.count
        }

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell: UITableViewCell

        if tableView == self.tableView1 {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            let dato = muestraDatos1[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel!.text = dato
        } else {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            let dato = muestraDatos2[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel!.text = dato
        }

        return cell

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        print("seleccionada fila:      \(indexPath.row)  ")

    }

}
```